# Qt PNG image not displaying

Tags: qt, qimage, qpixmap

I just cannot get the png image to display, I check that it loads correctly which is does but nothing is displayed on my blank canvases. The third one is meant to display an image. Can someone please have a quick look? Thanks.

```
QImage * QI = new QImage;
bool Check = QI->load("test.png");
QGraphicsPixmapItem * QII = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(*QI));

QRect ImagePanelArea1(0, MenuBarHeight, 
                      ScreenWidth / 3, (ScreenHeight / 2) - MenuBarHeight);
QRect ImagePanelArea2(ScreenWidth / 3, MenuBarHeight, 
                      ScreenWidth / 3, (ScreenHeight / 2) - MenuBarHeight);
QRect ImagePanelArea3((ScreenWidth / 3) * 2, MenuBarHeight, 
                      ScreenWidth / 3, (ScreenHeight / 2) - MenuBarHeight);

QGraphicsScene * QGS1 = new QGraphicsScene(ImagePanelArea1, this);
QGraphicsScene * QGS2 = new QGraphicsScene(ImagePanelArea2, this);
QGraphicsScene * QGS3 = new QGraphicsScene(ImagePanelArea3, this); 
QGS3->addItem(QII);

QGraphicsView * QGV1 = new QGraphicsView(QGS1, this); 
QGV1->setGeometry(ImagePanelArea1); 
QGV1->show();
QGraphicsView * QGV2 = new QGraphicsView(QGS2, this); 
QGV2->setGeometry(ImagePanelArea2); 
QGV2->show();
QGraphicsView * QGV3 = new QGraphicsView(QGS3, this); 
QGV3->setGeometry(ImagePanelArea3); QGV3->show();
```

Comment: Did you have all those qt image library installed? By default, the support library for svg, png and etc are not included.

Comment: What do you mean? I just installed the qt installer I have no idea sorry :(

Comment: see if you could find ``qtsvg4.dll`` and other image library.

Comment: I have a folder called qtsvg which contains src files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you item is not outside of your scene `QGS3`?

`QII` is at the position `(0;0)`. The `QRect` of your scene is defined between the point `((ScreenWidth / 3) * 2, MenuBarHeight)` and the point `(ScreenWidth / 3, (ScreenHeight / 2) - MenuBarHeight)`.

So, if your image is less larger than `(ScreenWidth / 3) * 2`, your item will be not visible.

Comment: My image is 64x64 pixels, and why would it not be displayed? I mean my scene views have borders on them so I assume the picture will simply need to be scrolled if its larger than them.